# Php/Bootstrap executes via localhost, but not from IDE (PhpStorm)

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a personal project at home, and I'm using Apache/Linux as my server, and PhpStorm as my IDE. I made it where I could just type in the domain name (myDomain.com/login.php) instead of "localhost/login.php". In my /etc/hosts file, I've resolved 127.0.0.1 to my domain name. All is well, and my code executes perfectly when accessing it directly. This is where my issue arises:

If I write some code within PhpStorm, and I execute from within the IDE, no php executes. It only works if I access it outside the IDE. I have correctly set up my php interpreter.

[image: PHP Interpreter for PhpStorm]

And I'm using port 63342 as required by PhpStorm.

[image: Port 63342 for Debugger]

Why is it that when I execute from the IDE, the php code doesn't execute? I can't register a new account, login, or even incorrectly login. It just refreshes the page.

To show that it works outside of the IDE, here is a snapshot of my Bootstrap alert-danger alert popping up upon invalid credentials:

[image: Bootstrap alert]

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I don't mind going back and forth between IDE and actual localhost. It would just be convenient to execute from within my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

To run the website via PhpStorm you need configure the PHP interpreter and the "Built-in Web Server" inside PhpStorm. Check this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/php-built-in-web-server.html).

Comment: Problem is that I tried that link first and it didn't work. My host is 'localhost', and my Document Root is /var/www/projectName/public_html.

Comment: What is the error message when you click in the "play" button?

Comment: Well whatta you know. I've been using the little browser launcher icons in the top right this whole time. I clicked the Run button and I got "Failed to listen on localhost:80 (reason: Permission denied)". I will do some research on that unless you get back to me before then.

Comment: Couldn't find much on the interwebs. I'm not sure if this is the correct way to fix it, but I went to Tools --> Deployment --> Configuration and set the Type to "Local or mounted folder", the Upload/Download project files to my project directory, and my Web Server root URL to http://myDomainName.net. I then clicked the little launcher Chrome icon and my php executed. :)

Comment: Hi. Failed to listem localhost:80 occurs because by default only root can start a process that run at port 80. Try to change to port 8080